# Quarto + git (not github) for tracking comments

Tags: git, comments, quarto, collaboration

I'm inexperienced in git but I would like to know if it make sense to try to keep track the in text comments by using git (not github).
Collaborative work with Quarto is an [issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/405) so my question here is if git could be helpful in keeping record of older comments and replies.

Comment: Why do you emphasize “not GitHub”? Simply not mentioning it is enough.

Comment: I don't think Git is a good choice here. The problem is asynchronicity; in terms of Git it's frequent pulling and resolving merge commits.

Comment: Out of the box, probably not. With some custom tooling and using something like `git notes`, maybe.

Comment: Check out hypothesis.is which `Quarto` makes easy to use, if your output is html.